# Can't locate infinite loop in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js, server-side-rendering

React is throwing the error `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` but I can't see the loop anywhere. Could someone help me out?

If I do `console.log((navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null))))` directly, it returns undefined (as `navs` is fetched after intial render) so I am forced to check if it is defined with `!!navs`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Config } from "../../config";

export default function Navbar() {
  const [navs, setNavs] = useState();
  const [mainNav, setMainNav] = useState({});

  useEffect(async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${Config.apiUrl}/navs`);
    const data = await res.json();
    setNavs(data);
  }, []);

  !!navs && setMainNav(navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null)));

  console.log(mainNav);

  return (
    <nav></nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're calling `setMainNav()` directly in the function unconditionally (once `navs` is truthy). setting `mainNav` doesn't affect what `navs` is.

Comment: I am checking if `navs` is defined before mapping through it and setting `mainNav`. What do you mean?

Comment: `.map` will ALWAYS return a new array, because arrays are stored by reference in Javascript. So even if elements are the same, the actual arrays are different. Wrap that code in a `useEffect` with `navs` as a dependency

Comment: When you set a state directly in the function component, it triggers it to render again with the new state. Once `navs` is truthy, calling your `setMainNav()` will never make it falsy, so it will re-render indefinitely.

Comment: Hi guys, so I've placed it in a `useEffect` but it is causing the page to rerender three times (the `console.log` is recording two empty objects and **then** the array.)
 
`useEffect(() => {
    !!navs && setMainNav(navs.map((x) => (x.name === "main-nav" ? x : null)));
  }, [navs]);`

Comment: @atman_lens that's correct. First render, `navs` is `undefined` and the first `useEffect()` fetches data to set `navs` to an array. Second render starts the second `useEffect()` and sets `mainNav` to an array based on `navs`, but for that second render, `mainNav` is still `{}`. Then on the third render, `mainNav` is your computed array, and no other effects are triggered.

Comment: According to your tags you are using `next.js`. So you could do the data call on the server side and pass in the data to your component. With this approach you have access to the data on the initial render.